# zsh ignore glob if nomatch

Tags: zsh, wildcards

To list all docker repositories I need to use an asterisk. But I am forced to add quotes because zsh globbing catches the asterisk.

```
sudo docker image list "hub.local/*"
```

I try aliasing with noglob, but sudo will fail, and docker needs sudo

```
alias docker="noglob docker"
```

I thought I could set zsh to not complain when it fails to match, but it seems zsh will remove the asterisk anyway.

```
setopt nomatch
```

I want to either disable zsh globbing entirely, or get zsh to pass through the globbing character if it fails to match. Or possibly set zsh globbing to behave like bash. I want to get around typing quotes all the time.

Comment: What is the actual argument that you want to pass to `docker`? Is it a list of filenames or a string with a `*` at the end?  If it's a string with a `*` at the end, quoting that string is the correct way of doing it. The question is otherwise a duplicate of [Getting sudo to work for an alias](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/109722) and other similar questions.

Comment: `setopt +o nomatch`, not `setopt nomatch`.

Comment: @Kusalananda the argument is a string with * at the end. I don't want to use quotes! I don't want zsh globbing when I'm not specifying files

Comment: @Kusalananda The command `sudo noglob docker` still fails after settings `alias sudo="sudo "`

Comment: @muru this is the answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alias docker='noglob sudo docker'
```

Would cause globs to never be expanded on a line that starts with `docker` and would run `docker` under `sudo`. If you still occasionally need to run `docker` not as root, you could make it a `sudo-docker` or `sdocker` alias instead.

I wouldn't recommend enabling the Bourne/`bash` behaviour which is really a bad design and is dangerous, but it you really wanted to, that could be done with `set +o nomatch` (or `setopt nonomatch` or `unsetopt nomatch`...).